# Error in Scanner with Integer Inputs

Tags: java

The sc.nextInt(); gives error for the sc. I am just trying to calculate the sum of x and y by assigning functions and calling them. It's just an assignment that I have to finish but unfortunately I asked my TA but he didn't know how to solve it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class calculator {

int x;
int y;

public void setnumber (){
    System.out.println("Please Enter X");
    x = sc.nextInt ();
    System.out.println("Please Enter Y");
    y = sc.nextInt ();
}

public void sum (){
    int sum = x + y;
    System.out.println ("The Sum" + sum);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    calculator sx = new calculator ();
    sx.setnumber ();
    sx.sum();
}
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: you need to pass the reference of the scanner object to the set number method .`public void setnumber(Scanner sc)  `

Comment: "I asked my TA but he didn't know how to solve it" Yikes.

Comment: either create your `Scanner` object in setnumber function or make `sc` global

Comment: "It just says build successful" it shouldn't be possible since you have compilation error in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move the scanner declaration to the setnumber method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class calculator {

int x;
int y;

public void setnumber (){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please Enter X");
    x = sc.nextInt ();
    System.out.println("Please Enter Y");
    y = sc.nextInt ();
}

public void sum (){
    int sum = x + y;
    System.out.println ("The Sum" + sum);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    calculator sx = new calculator ();
    sx.setnumber ();
    sx.sum();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks this did solve it. Do you mind explaining why this fixes it?

Comment: It fixes it because the visibility of the Scanner object is limited to the method in which it's declared. In your code the Scanner object is 'hidden' in the main method. I moved it to the method where you are referencing it.

Comment: Opening Scanner handling System.in in method can lead to few problems. Since we should ensure closing resources it would mean that we should at some point close that Scanner, which also means closing System.in. It is OK if we want to use this method only once and never again read from System.in, but if that is not the case then generally it is better to create single Scanner for System.in and pass it to method as argument. Then we can simply close this scanner at the end of main method, right before exit.

Answer (score 0):

Take Scanner sc out of the main method, define it at class level.

Comment: Scope should be limited. If the object is only used in one method, it should be declared in that method.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about scope.
The scanner object is not visible outside the main method